# Filepath of R-file influences the possibility to set breakpoints

Tags: r, debugging, breakpoints

Since I started using breakpoints, I experience that setting breakpoints in an R file sometimes works and somestimes doesn't, in a seemingly unsystematic way. My most recent observation was that switching the filepath of an R file can influence the possibility to set breakpoints. More specifically, I was already debugging some files in filepath A where I was able to set breakpoints. In another file, which was in filepath B, I was not able to set breakpoints (I get the warning message that the package should be build and reloaded although I am not building a package. Nothing happens if I source the file). However, when I put that file from filepath B to filepath A, I could magically set breakpoints all of a sudden without any problems. I am really struggling to find systematic behavior in when setting breakpoints works and when not. Any help if much appreciated.

Comment: You should write a bug report to RStudio in GitHub, especially if you are able to upload a file that experiences the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are a number of ways to approach debugging, but I just saw this nugget in `?trace` that hadn't occurred to me referring `at`, that to get the proper line you need to look at the function/script not as you do in your editor, but as it is seen by the compiler(?) via `as.list(body(your_function))` so everyone/thing is talking about the same line. Maybe this will help, otherwise show the steps you are taking with a misbehaving function and its associated data.